# amazon elb with multiple ssl sites on single ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-elb

I am running one ec2 with secondary IP on default lan card eth0 and running two sites with different ssl certs. When I add the instance in elb it replies only on primary IP. When I run https site my primary site is working but secondary ip site is not working. Then I tried site only on secondary IP. elb was giving blank page while I checked instance status and instance was in service state. Can you tell me about elb behaviour. It checks only primary IP of default lan card. So it's not responding for secondary IP site.

Looking for reply.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Are using VPCs? If not, I don't even think that Amazon allows you to have another IP address on the same eth0 interface. Once you launch an instance not in a VPC they automatically assign an internal IP address through their mechanisms which is probably DHCP.

You are probably better off running apache or nginx with virtualhosts running on different ports to service your https traffic from the ELB.

Hope it helps.